# Book recommendation for wavelet analysis

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, computer-science, machine-learning, wavelets

I am master student doing research in data mining, i read a paper about wavlet analysis for data mining, so i think it may help me in the future. But in my undergraduate degree the last course in mathematics was linear algebra, not higher than that. So i did not take Fourier analysis nor mathematical analysis, so what you suggest on me? Do you have a good books for my level?

Comment: Nice question. +1 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Wavelet-Analysis-David-Walnut/dp/0817639624](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639624)
2. [http://www.amazon.com/Wavelet-Analysis-Scalable-Structure-Information/dp/038798383X/ref=pd_bxgy_b_text_y](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/038798383X)

These are good books.

---

Also, some pdfs below :-

1. http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/
2. http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/bams_79_01_0061.pdf
3. http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/94dec/dec94a6a.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much, so do you i almost remember linear algebra! I hope introduction wavelet analysis will be good put in mind i don't know Fourier analysis too! 

So what about the second book? is't good for computer science and it's easy ?

Comment: @MohammadAhmed The first book is highly recommended; it'll teach you everything you need (Even Fourier Analysis). The second book is a bit difficult; read that after the first book. ( I.e. read this first: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0817639624/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 )

Comment: Also, welcome to Math StackExchange! Hope you have a wonderful time sir!

Comment: Thank you so much, i will keep using this group. So do you think according to my level ( almost calculus) i can understand the first book? Do you think it will be useful for me in computer science (data mining)?

Comment: You might want to learn calculus first; for references without much calculus you should use the pdfs. The first book needs one to calculus... so if you want to buy the book, then please do so only after having learnt calculus.

Comment: Ohh, i am in master and i forget a lot of calculas, but i will review it in one week, then go to buy the first  book, i have no time the course is for 1 month!! so i have no choice :/ 

Thank you for the first book, i will do by your advice.

Comment: what about this book, Wavelet Methods for Time Series Analysis (Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics)

Comment: 'The authors do not assume knowledge of Fourier analysis and cover the relevant theory in Chapter 2. The text tries to be self-contained and the authors start out at a very elementary level. They emphasize applications and practical aspects of wavelets.' Looks like you've got yourself a good book!

Comment: Which one i don't understand? Which book that is good luck? Do you mean Wavelet Methods for Time Series Analysis (Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics) or your first book? 

Actually i find book related to CS, but my problem still i need the easiest one that don't require Fourier analysis and instead explain them.

So again can you summarize your answer with a book :)

Comment: The book you told seems to be excellent.